# There is a сalculation error during addition of two numbers in Scala

Tags: scala, numbers, addition, operation

When I add two numbers together I get Calculation error like that:

0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004

Can I solve this problem without rounding the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.
Try googeling floating point arithmetic. That should answer all your questions.

https://0.30000000000000004.com/

["Floating point is broken" duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268446/floating-point-is-broken-duplicates)

https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: This is almost a link-only answer, the only saving grace is the "no". In the future it's best to at least summarize the information in the link. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288056/238704

Comment: It isn't. The link is merely an extra-hint. The main-part of this answer is the "keyword" floating point arithmetic. If you look that up in any search engine you'll instantly get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You also could use something different from `Double`, like `BigDecimal`:

```scala
BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1) + BigDecimal.valueOf(0.2)
```